# Threading Android execute void in the UI thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

right now i'm doing

```
public void someStuff(){
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //doing long task
            doOtherStuff();
        }
    }).start();
}

public void doOtherStuff(){
    doEvenMoreStuff();
}
```

but the problem is that it executes `doOtherStuff` in the same thread and It needs to be executed in the UI Thread. how can I accomplish this?

I am only using the thread because otherwise the app freezes. I just need `doOtherStuff` to wait for the thread to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

`this` is your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Use handler :

```
  public void doOtherStuff(){
    new Handler(context.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
          // Executes on UI thread
          doEvenMoreStuff();
        }
    });
  }
```

where `context` might be your `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if best practice but you can Try this:

```
public void someStuff(){
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      YourActivityClassName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {

           //doing long task
            doOtherStuff();
          }
      });

    }
}).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of using Handler which other answers suggested is  [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

It has two methods which can be useful in your case:

`doInBackground`: which runs in the background thread so your UI won't freeze

`onPostExecute`: which runs on UI thread after `doInBackground` finishes. A generic class may look like:

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... input) {
      //do background processes on input and send response to onPostExecute
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
       //update UIs based on the result from doInBackground
    }
  }
```

and you can execute the task by:

```
new MyTask(inputs).execute()
```